Noob support please

Hi, a starting out with Blender person here.
I’ve always and by that I mean always had this question: How do I fill a circle hole like this? When I try to alt+click an edge it just selects the edges of a face, and not the hole. And when i manually select edges and fill their bridges, it turns out sh!t.
Again, to recap: my questions are:

how do i select the edges quickly and effectively?
how to texture ANY round object, not just this one, like a pro
how to make the fill tool actually work (preferably no add-ons)

Huge thanks in advance.

Hello, select the 2 edge loops and Ctrl E > Bridge Edge Loops? As for the texture select the face ring, choose the front view and U > Cylinder Projection?

@moonboots THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!!!!!!!!! Finally some person is helpful in months

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

Select the 2 edge loops and CtrlE > Bridge Edge Loops (or enable the LoopTools addon and right click > LoopTools > Bridge). As for the texture select the face ring, switch to front view and U > Cylinder Projection.
